# Rails Tutorial Multiple Logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, basic-authentication

I built a little news reader and worked through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial for the authentication. I'd like to add the feature so multiple people can login at the same time, basically to share the remember token I guess?

Here's what the `sessions_helper.rb` file looks like:

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
end
```

From what I can tell, it seems what happens is that when a user signs in it generates a new token, which wipes out the old one.

Luckily it's not something that needs to be secure, so I don't necessarily need to generate a new one on each login, i could keep the same token for weeks.

The end all goal is to be able to sign in from my work computer, as well as personal one and not have to keep logging in each time.

I'd appreciate any guidance, I'm new to Rails but I'm really enjoying it and picking it up nicely.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about what you meant by multiple logging in and sharing remember_token. Do you mean a number of people sharing a same account?

Just to help clarify the log in mechanisms in the tutorial, Hartl provides two different types of authentications.
First one uses temporary cookie called sessions, which expires once you close the browser, and hence you are automatically logged out of the application.

The second system adds a layer on top of the first one by using a semi-permanent cookie. If you fill in the log in information and check the 'remember me' toggle, the second mechanism is invoked, whereby remember_token(this is what you were referring to) is generated and cached in your browser as a cookie, and hashed and saved in the database as remember_digest column. So that even if you close the browser and come back, the semi-permanent cookie(remember_token) stored in the browser gets hashed and compared to the remember_digest in the database and keeps you logged in if they match. A new remember_token is generated and hashed and stored in database every time you explicitly log out and log back in.

So following the tutorial, you have two options to implement authentication:

1) just use temporary cookie, which doesn't require remember_token and remember_digest(database).

2) use both temporary cookie and semi-permanent, which does require hitting the database.